# How to pass List of Widgets in children property of another Widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

Taking the following function as example:

```
List<Widget> getListFiles() {
    List<Widget> list = [
        Container(),
        Container(),
        Container(),
    ];

    return list;
}
```

How to insert into a children param?

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>
    [
        Text(),
        Text(),
        getListFiles(), <---
        Text(),
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update**

Now Dart has spread operator with the version 2.3.

```
[
  ...anotherList
  item1
]
```

**Answer without Spread operator**

I think you need to spread your list since you can't assign element type 'List' to the list type 'Widget'. `Spread operator` is a feature that wanted. You can follow the issue about it on [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/47).

Meanwhile you can use `generators` and `yield` operator.

```
Column(
  children: List.unmodifiable(() sync* {
    yield Text();
    yield Text();
    yield* getListFiles();
    yield Text();
  }()),
);
```

Full code of the usage in widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Widget> getListFiles() {
    List<Widget> list = [Text('hello'), Text('hello1'), Text('hello2')];

    return list;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Stackoverflow'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: List.unmodifiable(() sync* {
          yield Text('a');
          yield Text('b');
          yield* getListFiles();
          yield Text('c');
        }()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Now you can use the spread operator - Since dart 2.3.0

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>
    [
        Text(),
        Text(),
        ...getListFiles(), <---
        Text(),
    ]
)
```

Additionally you may have to change the minimum SDK level in the pubspec.yaml to 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you have a list of custom widgets to show in the **Column**.

*Custom Widget*

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback selectHandler; // property holds the function.
  final String answerText;

  ...
}
```

**Using List Literal**: The list of *Answer Widget* can be called inside column as below,

```
 Column(
      children: [
        const Text('Question'),
        ...([
          Answer(_answerQuestion, 'Answer 1'),
          Answer(_answerQuestion, 'Answer 2')
        ])
      ],
    )
```

**From List**: Map list of custom widgets with help of list property.

```
// List<String> property.
var answers = ['Black', 'Red', 'Green'];
// Pass in the list of custom widgets inside Column as follows.
...answers.map((answer) => Answer(_answerQuestion, answer))
```

**Using the list from List<Map<String, Object>>**: If you have a complex structure, preparing custom widgets of *Answer* from the list of 'answers' will be implemented as below.

```
// List<Map<String, Object>> property. 
var questions = [
  {
    'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
    'answers': ['Black', 'Red', 'Green']
  }
];
    
// Pass in the list of custom widgets inside Column as follows.
...(questions.first['answers'] as List<String>)
                .map((answer) => Answer(_answerQuestion, answer))
```